# Wisdom says "don't use globals"

Tags: ios

A global is a piece of data that is accessible in every context by name.

Comment: Well, "wisdom" also says that [singletons are an anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/126172/189950)...

Comment: +1 just for question why there is a norm, and not just follow it blindly...

Comment: The "don't use globals" thing is taught in school so the kids will stop turning in homework where all the functions take no parameters and just work from globals. You know, like BASIC forced you to do back in the early 80's, along with forcing you to use GOTO.

Answer (score 4):

You may heard that "there is an exception to each rule".

I have been programming for several years, and before there was this "hip" of singletons, I started using global variables in my programs.

But, eventually, the programs switched to handle most variables as local, wheter classes fields, or methods fields.

It just came naturally, and it seems that a lot of developers, actually came to the same conclusion, before, after, and the same time, than me ;-)

In most O.O. programming languages, the program itself, is considered an object, and therefore a singleton.

Sometimes, several required global variables, wheter objects or non objects fields, can be encapsulated as a singleton.

Singleton as any other "better practice" or "design pattern", should be used wisely,
learn when & why are useful, and when not to apply.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general idea is that there is not really "global" data.  You may consider a program's user information (name, password, hair color) to be global, and in practice it may be.  But it is conceivable (maybe using sockets) that other users might become active in the same session.  You need a class (User) for this information and, *now*, several instances of it.  And when you need this information, you need the right instance of User at hand.  (The correct User object must be passed into the method, or must be available in an instance field; just getting the value from MainClass.userInfo won't work anymore.)

If you originally wrote the program with the idea that there might be multiple users and so far it's never been enhanced to handle them, your User class instance is a singleton and, in a sense, a "global" object as well.  But your code will be more intelligible, and in the rare event multiple users *are* needed, easily upgradable.

Comment: And yet, when writing code for something simple, like a dishwasher, an assumption like "there is only one control panel" *makes perfect sense* for the indefinite future and you have no reason to make things more complex than they need to be.

Comment: No point in doing extra work for code you'll never touch again.  However, the immediate additional complexity is usually very minor, while the work to add the capability later can be massive.  The effort to avoid using global data to store 10 items can pay off big even if only one of them is ever upgraded.  And knowing that upgrading is easy may inspire people to enhance the program and/or use it to do new jobs rather than live with its defects or replace it completely--even if they never actually need to upgrade any of the 10.

Comment: Or you could put related items, such as User info, into a single class and instantiate one as a singleton/global. So, initially you only have to write the code that is actually needed (e.g. forego multi-User because it's a single-user system).  Then, later, if multi-User is desired, it's all in one place already and you just have to search and replace the global. This strategy works for many cases, because people are usually pretty bad at predicting whether or not a feature will be needed in the future.